# How to check OS detailed information of Azure virtual machine using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, azure-python-sdk

I have written this code to list down the Azure Virtual Machine. Now I want to print all the details related to the `OS` `disks` such as OS, `disk` `size`, `encryption` `settings`, and other  details related to Azure Virtual Machine

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

Subscription_Id = "XXXX"
Tenant_Id = "XXXX"
Client_Id = "XXXX"
Secret = "XXXX"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id=Client_Id,
    client_secret=Secret,
    tenant_id=Tenant_Id
)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credential=credential, subscription_id=Subscription_Id)
resource_list = resource_client.resources.list()
for item in resource_list:
    if(item.type == 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'):
        print(item.name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure python sdk get attributes from virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451789/azure-python-sdk-get-attributes-from-virtual-machine)

Comment: You can refer to [Python Azure sdk - Enabling Disk Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785672/python-azure-sdk-enabling-disk-encryption) and [Azure Virtual Machines Management Samples - Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/azure-virtual-machines-management-samples---python/)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT this is my output it does not have the key name `encryption` or `storage_profile` how can I get it `" 'name': 'Linux', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', 'location': 'eastus', 'extended_location': None, 'tags': None, 'plan': None, 'properties': None, 'kind': None, 'managed_by': None, 'sku': None, 'identity': None, 'created_time': None, 'changed_time': None, 'provisioning_state': None"`

Comment: Could you please try to use `os_disk_name = virtual_machine.storage_profile.os_disk.name
os_disk = compute_client.disks.get(GROUP_NAME, os_disk_name)` as mentioned in this [GitHub](https://github.com/azure-samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/tree/master/#retrieving-a-vms-os-disk) sample.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `storage_profile` you can use the below example of code with `list all` :

```
vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()

filtered = [vm for vm in vm_list if vm.name == "MY_VM_NAME"] 
vm = filtered[0] #First VM

print("\nstorageProfile")
print("  imageReference")
print("    publisher: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.publisher)
print("    offer: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.offer)
print("    sku: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.sku)
print("    version: ", vm.storage_profile.image_reference.version)
print("  osDisk")
print("    osType: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.os_type.value)
print("    name: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.name)
print("    createOption: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.create_option.value)
print("    caching: ", vm.storage_profile.os_disk.caching.value)
```

For Complete setup please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:*** [***Create and manage Windows VMs in Azure using Python***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python#get-information-about-the-vm)

For more information please refer this ***SO THREAD:*** [***How could I list details of only 1 Azure Virtual Machines using Python?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691212/how-could-i-list-details-of-only-1-azure-virtual-machines-using-python)